# IIS Express stops responding to all requests after brief inactivity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application, and when I run it from VS, if I let the browser sit on a page for a short time like 45 seconds, and then try to take some action, the request never makes it to my controller. Everything functions as expected if I don't wait at all before making a navigation/request. This problem has existed for the life of the project.

The IIS Express logs do not show any requests when this happens; however, in debug mode, VS can see that the browser did make a request. No breakpoints inside of the ActionResult get hit though, so I know it isn't getting called. The browser's debug tools show the request sitting in the pending state forever. The website is still running though, IIS doesn't crash. I can open another browser and access the login page, however, the POST doesn't fire the controller action.

This happens on every machine and with every browser. I've scoured the web and couldn't find others with my problem. My webconfig and applicationHosts look like the default generated ones, except for some forms auth settings.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: You could get a memory dump of the IIS process that is hosting your app once it hangs and use [Debug Diagnostic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) to analyze the dump to see if there is something odd there.

Comment: Also write a method  for [Global.Application_End Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee255094(v=bts.10).aspx) and add some diagnostic logging to see if your app is stopping on its own or not. Do the same for `Global.Application_Error` as well.

Comment: @Igor Neither of those functions are ever called. IIS doesn't seem to be crashing either, it's running, just not handling requests.

Comment: Then I would proceed with the memory dump, you can analyze the threads and call stacks to see if there is anything out of the ordinary. There are built in commands like `!analyze` to see if there is/are threads hanging.

Comment: @Igor Thanks, the Debug Analysis found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a loader lock being made by a thread that was dying (terminated?) before it could release the lock. This lock would block any threads handling HTTP requests. Application Insights appeared in the callstack for the problematic thread, and after disabling it, the problem no longer occurs.